# Custom carousel in experience site

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience, third-party

I am trying to display a simple carousel in a community site. The carousel should approximatively be as below :
[image]

I am trying to find the simple way to do that, so I created a LWC and tried to integrate with the [slick framework](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Questions:

1 - Is there any simple way to do that? maybe using Visualforce page or aura component.

2 - Based on [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library) and the [slick documentation](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), I tried to integrate the slick framework, but it does not seems to work. Is it something possible to do? What is wrong in the code?

HTML

```
    <template>
       <div class="your-class" id="testId1" lwc:dom="manual">
       </div>
       <div onclick={onclick1}>
          test onclick
       </div>
    </template>
```

JS
(the slickJS resource contains the download zip from [here](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/))

```
    import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
    import getContentDocumentsByLibrary from '@salesforce/apex/CustomCarousel_Crtl.getContentDocumentsByLibrary';
    import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
    import JQUERY from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jquery';
    import SLICKJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/slickJS';
    
    
    
    export default class CustomCarousel extends LightningElement {
    
        slickInitialized = false;
    
        renderedCallback() {
            debugger;
            if (this.slickInitialized) {
                return;
            }
            this.slickInitialized = true;
    
            Promise.all([
                loadScript(this, JQUERY+ '/jquery.js'),
            ])
                .then(() => {
                    debugger;
                    Promise.all([
                        loadStyle(this, SLICKJS + '/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css'),
                        loadStyle(this, SLICKJS + '/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css'),
                        loadScript(this, SLICKJS + '/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js')
                    ])
                        .then(() => {
                            debugger;
                            this.initializeSlick();
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            debugger;
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    
        initializeSlick() {
            debugger;
            // here I adding the divs in the main div 
            $(this.template.querySelector('.your-class')).slick();
            // $('.your-class').slick();
        }
    
        onclick1() {
            debugger;
        }
}
```